# How to send csrf token in ajax requests for django 1.11+

Tags: django

Apparently 1.11 will start to make use of storing the csrf token in sessions ([source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/#std:setting-CSRF_USE_SESSIONS)). Although cookies will still be available, at the moment I'm sending ajax requests with the token in the header:

```
XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader("X-CSRFToken", csrftoken);
```

How would sessions change what I have to do with my ajax requests for them to pass csrf security checks?

Comment: I don't think it would, it says it defaults to False so that wouldn't change your current usage. Or are you asking what you'd have to do if you decide to set this to true?

Comment: Yes, if I don't use cookies anymore, how do I send a valid XMLHttpRequest that passes csrf verification?